INDEX Enable Disable in ORACLE table
I have one table which is having four indexes and 6 constraints. Now I have to load 13 millions data into this table from another table(Single table). When I am doing it it is taking 10 minutes to complete(Even more). So I decided, before inserting into this table I would disable constraints and Indexes. It is working fine and completing comparatively in lesser time. But the problem is when I am trying to rebuilding the indexes, it is taking same amount of time. Any idea how to approach this situation?
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE CONSTRAINT cons1;
ALTER INDEX index_name UNUSABLE;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE table_name';
               
INSERT /* APPEND PARALLEL(8) */ INTO table_name SELECT /*+ parallel(8) */ * FROM source_table;


ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE NOVALIDATE CONSTRAINT cons1;
ALTER INDEX index_name REBUILD ONLINE;


Did you try to disable only the constraint but not the index? In this case, the rebuild should not be needed.

@WernfriedDomscheit, sorry I have given wrong command earlier. I have edited them.

You probably just need to enable parallel dml and fix your broken hint - it isn't a hint without the + following the comment start (it should be /*+, not /* ) :
alter session enable parallel dml;

INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL(8) */ INTO table_name . . .

PDML will postpone index maintenance. It should rebuild the indexes for you so there may be no need to disable/rebuild the indexes, though you may want to mark the indexes with parallelism: alter index index_name parallel(degree 8) (once, not every time) which can make a difference with some DDL operations.
If you still want to disable and rebuild, that's fine, just rebuild with parallelism:
alter index index_name rebuild parallel (degree 8)

Don't use the ONLINE option unless you have to. Since you just reloaded the table chances are you don't have users modifying the table at this time anyway, so ONLINE just slows things down for no reason.
If your constraint is a foreign key you are right to disable it (though if this is a regular process then I'd question the usefulness of a foreign key in the first place). But if it's just a check constraint or a NOT NULL there's no penalty to loading with it enabled. If it's a UK/PK created without an existing index (e.g. it implicitly created a supporting index when the constraint was added) then disabling it will drop the underlying index and allow the load. If it's a UK/PK created using an existing index, Oracle won't allow the load at all with the index in an unusable state. You'd have to manually drop the index and recreate it. All things considered, it's probably best just to use PDML and take advantage of the postponed index maintenance, which should perform pretty close to a rebuild.
